# compare 2 web.config and merge data into another file

Tags: asp.net, powershell

How to compare two web.config files and replace changes into second file.

I tried with Powershell, changed text is displayed but not replaced into 2nd web.config can anybody help me into it.

Below is the Powershell code

```
clear-host
$strFile1 = get-Content "C:\config_files_1\web.config"
$strFile2 = get-Content "C:\config_files_2\web.config"
Compare-Object $strFile1 $strFile2
```

**My 1st config code:**

```
<appSettings>
        **<add key="SQLConnString" value=" Data Source=Test;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=pwd;Application Name=Test;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>**
        <!--RTL Setting-->
        <add key="MappingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="MappingServer" value=""/>
        <add key="MappingUser" value="SuperAdmin"/>
        <add key="MappingPassword" value="SuperAdmin"/>
        <add key="MaximumUserRecentItems" value="10"/>
        <add key="LoginBannerURL" value=""/>
        <add key="LoginBannerTimeout" value=""/>
        <add key="EmailNotificationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="ErrorNotificationLevel" value="2"/>
        <add key="NotificationEmailAddress" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
```

**2nd Config code is:**

```
<appSettings>
**<add key="SQLConnString" value=" Data Source=Prod;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=ProdDB;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=pwd;Application Name=Prod;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>**
        <!--RTL Setting-->
        <add key="MappingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="MappingServer" value=""/>
        <add key="MappingUser" value="SuperAdmin"/>
        <add key="MappingPassword" value="SuperAdmin"/>
        <add key="MaximumUserRecentItems" value="10"/>
        <add key="LoginBannerURL" value=""/>
        <add key="LoginBannerTimeout" value=""/>
        <add key="EmailNotificationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="ErrorNotificationLevel" value="2"/>
        <add key="NotificationEmailAddress" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
```

One line is changed in both the files i.e.,

```
<add key="SQLConnString" value=" Data Source=Prod;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=ProdDB;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=pwd;Application Name=Prod;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
```

replaced text need to be merge into second file.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, *please* highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: why dont you just overwrite the bad file with the good file instead of trying to replace text inside of it

Comment: What is the point of merging the change? Overwriting the file would achieve the same result. It wouldnt be simple to know _where_ to put the change is part of the issue.

Comment: You can use WinMerge (download at [http://winmerge.org/](http://winmerge.org/) which is a free open source tool that allows you to compare the two files line by line and perform any changes you need. It also has a nice GUI so it's easier to identify issues

Comment: I need a tool or power shell code to run in client machine. Winmerge is not good to Install in client machine.

Comment: Matt is right, trying to find the line of text to change is a difficult procedure when overwriting the file achieves the same result with a relatively tiny amount of code. Is there a reason why you need to merge the changes rather than overwrite the entire file?